# Bug in Sequelize Update while updating large hash value

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

There is a weird issue popping out while updating a large hash value using sequleize.
I have a hash having

```
value='eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6Ijk0NDY5YWY1MjdkM2RlZjBkZGMxYTRlYWU1MjdmZWQ0IiwiaWF0IjoxNTQyMTgxMzkwLCJleHAiOjE1NDIxOTIxOTB9.SxShzkA_j3wSprlt8bHwJwzxirQ-'
```

and  have update a hash attribute of my table using the following:

```
TempUser.update( {hash:hash}, { where: { user: req.body.TempUser.user } } );
```

and the result in a log is

```
UPDATE temp_user SET hash='$2a$10$e35JRfRZdyitrkJOtrogOeuCUq1Dtwz9I0jHRytRv2z.zEYAmul9K',updated_at='2018-11-14 07:34:32' WHERE user = 'd@d.com'.
```

I cannot figure out why this is happening.

I have raised this issue in github too. dont why it is repeatedly closed.
    https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/10161

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: Say I have  a hash value And i am trying to update hash attribute of my table using Sequlize's update function. The value which is updated is not the same which i supplied. Can you check the question once.

Comment: I think the `hash` variable does not contain the value you are expecting because on your log it clearly shows a bcrypt hash. while the `value` you're showing is base64.

Comment: can you provide more of your relevant code? might as well just be `{hash: value}` maybe.

Comment: I have checked it, its there.. One value goes to mail and one to mysql through sequelize. In email, expected value is there but in mysql its not.

Comment: cant help you without more code. nothing wrong with your code. and this is clearly not a bug.

Comment: its same as written above.  hash='eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6Ijk0NDY5YWY1MjdkM2RlZjBkZGMxYTRlYWU1MjdmZWQ0IiwiaWF0IjoxNTQyMTgxMzkwLCJleHAiOjE1NDIxOTIxOTB9.SxShzkA_j3wSprlt8bHwJwzxirQ-'  TempUser.update( {hash:hash}, { where: { user: req.body.TempUser.user } });

Comment: well, `hash` could be a special keyword for sequelize where it automatically hashes the `hash` keyword with bcrypt. try changing the column name. or you are really providing the wrong variable or checking the wrong log.

Comment: what is the definition of the TempUser model?

Comment: thanks@majidarif..  well thats not the issue , it was hook which was producing that unexpected output.. Closing this thread now

Comment: Which is why we needed more of the code. Ciao

Answer (score 0):

I think your column size of `varchar` is not enough to  store that hashed value. Try to change your `hash` column size to be `VARCHAR(500)` or above